# django include template from another app

Tags: django, templates

While setting up my project and working to keep apps non-dependent, I've hit a snag. I'd like all of the templates from the different apps to have a consistent header and footer. Here's what I'm trying:

```
myproject/
         base/
             templates/
                      header.html
                      footer.html
         app1/
             templates/
                      my_app1_page.html -> want to include 'header.html'
                                           and 'footer.html' from base app
```

Pretend there are many more apps that want to do this as well. Is this possible and/or the right way to do it?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

As long as the apps are in INSTALLED_APPS and the template loader for apps dirs is enabled, you can include any template from another app, i.e.:

```
{% include "header.html" %}
```

... since your templates are located directly in the templates dir of your app.
Generally, in order to avoid name clashes it is better to use:

```
app1/
    templates/
        app1/
            page1.html
            page2.html
app2/
    templates/
        app2/
            page1.html
            page2.html
```

And `{% include "app1/page1.html" %}` or  `{% include "app2/page1.html" %}` ...

**But**: for keeping a consistent look and feel, it is so much better to use template inheritance rather than inclusion. Template inheritance is one of the **really good things** of the Django template system, choose inheritance over inclusion whenever it makes sense (most of the time).

My recommendations:

- Have a base template for your project ("base.html" is the default convention) with header and footer and a `{%block content%}` for your main content.
- Have your other templates inherit form base.html `{% extends "base.html" %}` and override the content section

See another response to this question for links to the doc

Comment: I just want extend the advice a little bit for people who are new to django that may consider include function a bad practice: 

WHILE I agree, it is indeed good to make use of inheritance, it is not quite correct to say it's better than include option. It just has a different purpose. It is a good tool to handle smaller html snippets (like modules/widgets in popular cms like Wordpress) . For example, you may want to list all categories from your blog, in a second app - without {% include %} option you MAY realize that you would have to rewrite same code in both applications.

Answer (score 11):

While you can certainly do that by using the [include tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include) and specifying absolute paths, the proper way to work in Django is by using [Template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#id1).

Comment: What if I have some model and partial template to render that model - e.g. address, event? I think, that inclusion makes sense in such scenario.

Comment: there is no way inheriting is a correct substitute for importing

Answer (score 3):

If you start a project with "$ django-admin startproject project" a folder named "project-folder-name" i.e. project/ is created. After adding a few apps and adding the apps in the "settings.py" -> INSTALLED_APPS=[..., app1, app2] and creating a templates folder within the project/ I got structure like this:

```
project/
    project/
        templates/
            base.html
    app1/
        templates/
            app1/
                page1.html
                page2.html
    app2/
        templates/
            app2/
                page1.html
                page2.html
```

in template app1/template/page1.html I wrote

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

and the "TemplateDoesNotExist at /" Error message appeared.

Then I added another App named "core" and added base.html to the template folder (+edit INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py) and i got this structure now:

```
project/
    project/
        templates/    (unused)
            base.html (not seen)
    core/
        templates/
            base.html
    app1/
        templates/
            app1/
                page1.html
                page2.html
    [...]
```

Now the error message disappears and the base.html is found with templates/app1/page1.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

You can change the folder structure like this:

```
    core/
        templates/
            core/
                base.html
```

then you need to change the template app1/page1.html to

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
```

as well.

As an alternative you can also add "your-project-name" in this explaination "project" into your settings file like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'project', # your project name main folder
    'core',
    'App1',
    'App2',
]
```

And now django finds the project/templates/base.html as well. However I don't know if this solution is recommended.

```
project/
    project/
        templates/    
            base.html (now it is found)
```

P.S. Thanks (my upvotes aren't counted yet) and comment me if this answer was somehow clear and understandable