# How to extend templates from different app Django with Jinja?

Tags: django, jinja2

I found that I have many Django projects and I want to extract all common features into an app.
When working with extract the Django template I got this problem.
Here is the app structure

```
myproject/
         app1/
             jinja2/
                    app1/
                          app1.html
         app2/
             jinja2/
                    app2/
                          app2.html
```

From `app2.html` I want to extend `app1.html`
What I try to do:

```
{% extend app1/app1.html %}
```

I get jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound app1/app1.html

Jinja2 setting in `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    { 
        'BACKEND':'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
    'DIRS': [ PROJECT_DIR / 'jinjatemplates' ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        },
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I got similar question here
[django include template from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571686/django-include-template-from-another-app)

Fixed: Can fix by adding the directory into template setting